# SQL: New column (categories) based on criteria from other table

Tags: sql-server, grouping, window-functions, partition

I'm trying to create a new table that will act as a page-level security filter on a Power BI report. I have two tables, doc_class and comp_class, which are routinely updated and do all the calculations I need. I simply need a new table that will assign page access based on an OwnerID's presence in the doc_class table.

Any OwnerID in the doc_class table needs access to two Power BI pages: Doctor and Doctor ROI
**ALL** OwnerIDs in the comp_class table need access to a different set of two pages: Practice and Practice ROI.
All OwnerIDs in doc_class are also in comp_class, if that makes any difference.
Page levels needs to each have their own row, and that is the part that is tripping me up.

Here are example tables (IDs only--the other data does not matter in this use case):

```
doc_class:      
| OwnerID  |
| -------- |
| 2        |
| 3        |

comp_class:
| OwnerID |
| --------|
| 1       |
| 2       |
| 3       |
| 4       |
```

Expected result:

```
| OwnerID  | page         |
| -------- | ------------ |
| 1        | Practice     |
| 1        | Practice ROI |
| 2        | Doctor       |
| 2        | Doctor ROI   |
| 2        | Practice     |
| 2        | Practice ROI |
| 3        | Doctor       |
| 3        | Doctor ROI   |
| 3        | Practice     |
| 3        | Practice ROI |
| 4        | Practice     |
| 4        | Practice ROI |
```

Comment: If "ALL OwnerIDs in the comp_class table need access to a different set of two pages: Practice and Practice ROI", why in the "expected result" table we have 4 => Doctor and 4 => Doctor ROI, instead of 4 => Practice and 4 => Practice ROI ?  I don't understand.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: @UltraCommit Sorry, that was a mistake. It's fixed now. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT cc.ownerID, 'Practice' page
  FROM comp_class cc
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
          (SELECT 1
             FROM doc_class dc
            WHERE dc.ownerID = cc.ownerID)
UNION ALL
SELECT ownerID, 'Practice ROI' page
  FROM comp_class cc
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
          (SELECT 1
             FROM doc_class dc
            WHERE dc.ownerID = cc.ownerID)
UNION ALL
SELECT dc.ownerID, 'Doctor' page
  FROM doc_class dc
 WHERE EXISTS
          (SELECT 1
             FROM comp_class cc
            WHERE cc.ownerID = dc.ownerID)
UNION ALL
SELECT dc.ownerID, 'Doctor ROI' page
  FROM doc_class dc
 WHERE EXISTS
          (SELECT 1
             FROM comp_class cc
            WHERE cc.ownerID = dc.ownerID)
UNION ALL
SELECT dc.ownerID, 'Practice' page
  FROM doc_class dc
 WHERE EXISTS
          (SELECT 1
             FROM comp_class cc
            WHERE cc.ownerID = dc.ownerID)
UNION ALL
SELECT dc.ownerID, 'Practice ROI' page
  FROM doc_class dc
 WHERE EXISTS
          (SELECT 1
             FROM comp_class cc
            WHERE cc.ownerID = dc.ownerID);
```

[image]

Comment: Ah man, I thought I was going to need to use a window function. Didn't even think of union. Anyways, thank you! 
I was able to simplify this a bit and get the same results:

SELECT distinct(cc.OwnerDID), 'Practice' page
  FROM comp_class cc

UNION ALL
SELECT distinct(OwnerDID), 'Practice ROI' page
  FROM comp_class cc

UNION ALL
SELECT dc.OwnerDID, 'Doctor' page
  FROM doc_class dc

UNION ALL
SELECT dc.OwnerDID, 'Doctor ROI' page
  FROM doc_class dc

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution. `Union` removes duplicates so you can take advantage of that. Also using `cross apply` makes code easier to read.

```
-- Any OwnerID in the doc_class table needs access to two Power BI pages: Doctor and Doctor ROI
select OwnerID, [Page] 
from doc_class
    cross apply (
        select 'Doctor' [Page] union all
        select 'Doctor ROI' [Page]
    ) p

UNION

-- ALL OwnerIDs in the comp_class table need access to a different set of two pages: Practice and Practice ROI.
select OwnerID, [Page]  
from comp_class
    cross apply (
        select 'Practice' [Page] union all
        select 'Practice ROI' [Page]
    ) p
```